Long unbreakable text in notification summary causes timestamps to overflow in global inbox
There's an item in my inbox for which the relative timestamp (2 days) overflows the envelope icon to mark it as (un)read:

This happens in several browsers (Safari and Chrome on macOS, Edge on Windows) through with Firefox on macOS everything looks normal:

After tweaking the content a bit with the browser developer tools, I think it's caused by the rather long URL in the summary of the item; if I introduce a whitespace there, the problem is gone.

Thanks @ShadowWizard, couldn't find that question because it wasn't tagged [tag:global-inbox]

Fair, I just remembered I posted something similar, and through that found the actual dupe. :)
